# How to calculate energy loss in a rotating shaft?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, friction, dissipation

Please help me with proper formula for below example.

Imagine a rotating shaft 'X' with 2 gear wheels 'a' and 'b' of same dimensions.  If energy applied to gear 'a' on the shaft through  source A what will be the output on gear 'b' ?  What factors will determine the loss of energy ? Is there a formula that I can use to find loss of energy for different gear dimensions for a and b ?  I am not a mechanical engineer but I have physics back ground. Please help me.

If you can suggest where I can find this information. That will also can help me. Kind regards.

Comment: If you ignore the frictional losses for some time, will the weight of the shaft and distance between 2 gear wheels a and b effect the energy loss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'formula' is the Principle of Conservation of Energy.

Whatever energy (work) is put in via gear wheel 'a' is either dissipated as friction in the gears or bearings, or increases the rotational KE of the gearshaft, or appears as work done on the output from gear wheel 'b'.  I assume the gearshaft is balanced so there is no change in its gravitational PE.  However, there could be some elastic energy stored in the torsional strain of the shaft.

There is no general formula to work out how the input energy is distributed between the different components.  This distribution will depend on whether a steady state has been reached, in which there is no rotational acceleration of the moving parts.  All of the input power will then appear either as output or as frictional losses.

Answer (score 0):

Energy lost is due to sliding friction when the gear teeth engage and disengage. Most gears are designed with involute profiles which allow rolling about the contact point when the contact force peaks (at the pitch circle). So the actual energy loss comes from a scrub calculation where the frictional force is multiplied with the scrub velocity to determine the scrub power loss. This power is integrated over the time of one tooth engagement to come up with the energy loss per tooth.

There is an additional energy lost from the elastic deformation in the material under the contact due to hysteresis (work hardening of the material), but this is a lot harder to quantify. It manifests itself as a reduction in rebound force compared to the impact force at each gear tooth contact.

So you need the geometry of the geartrain, the loads applied through the gear, the friction and lubrication conditions and the speed of rotation. Best to find a book on gear design and I am sure there is going to be a section on friction loss calculations.

Comment: If you ignore the frictional losses for some time, will the weight of the shaft and distance between 2 gear wheels a and b effect the energy loss?

Comment: How? Energy _loss_ means work goes into heat and dissipates into the environment. What you are talking about is energy _storage_ when some work goes into the kinetic energy of the parts, only to be recovered later.